# Need some advice on dissecting Qt compile error

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am having some issue with the autogenerated code by Qt's `Q_MOC_OUTPUT_REVISION`.

Essentially when I click to build, I get the errors below. I am not entirely sure what it all means and I have been busy for the past hour trying to figure out what it means but I would appreciate a more informed explanation of what the errors mean and how I can go about get rid of them.

```
class Product: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString _productid READ _productid WRITE _productid)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString _productcategoryid READ _productcategoryid WRITE _productcategoryid)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString _name READ _name WRITE _name)
    Q_PROPERTY(Productcontent * contents READ contents WRITE contents)//dynamic allocation of space for contents
    Q_PROPERTY(QString _productimagepath READ _productimagepath WRITE _productimagepath)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString _producticonpath READ _producticonpath WRITE _producticonpath )
    Q_PROPERTY(QString _productPrice READ _productPrice WRITE _productPrice )

    //since this does not change for each product, no need resending it each time
public:

    static const string _xmldocpath;
    static const string rootitemname;
    static const string tagname;
    QString _productid;
    QString _name;
    QString _productcategoryid;
    QString _productimagepath;
    QString _producticonpath;
    QString _productPrice;

    Product();
    //           const std::string &getfilepath();
    //           const std::string &getproducttagname();
    // bool UpdateProductData(string id);
    Q_INVOKABLE int FindProductByID(QString id);
    ~Product();
public slots:

signals:

};
```

The following error results. I have no idea how to disect this one. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
 debug\moc_product.cpp: In member function 'virtual int Productcontent::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)':
debug\moc_product.cpp:77: error: no match for call to '(QString) ()'
debug\moc_product.cpp:78: error: no match for call to '(QString) ()'
debug\moc_product.cpp:84: error: no match for call to '(QString) (QString&)'
debug\moc_product.cpp:85: error: no match for call to '(QString) (QString&)'
debug\moc_product.cpp: In member function 'virtual int Product::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)':
debug\moc_product.cpp:179: error: no match for call to '(QString) ()'
debug\moc_product.cpp:180: error: no match for call to '(QString) ()'
debug\moc_product.cpp:181: error: no match for call to '(QString) ()'
debug\moc_product.cpp:182: error: 'contents' was not declared in this scope
debug\moc_product.cpp:183: error: no match for call to '(QString) ()'
debug\moc_product.cpp:184: error: no match for call to '(QString) ()'
debug\moc_product.cpp:185: error: no match for call to '(QString) ()'
debug\moc_product.cpp:191: error: no match for call to '(QString) (QString&)'
debug\moc_product.cpp:192: error: no match for call to '(QString) (QString&)'
debug\moc_product.cpp:193: error: no match for call to '(QString) (QString&)'
debug\moc_product.cpp:194: error: 'contents' was not declared in this scope
debug\moc_product.cpp:195: error: no match for call to '(QString) (QString&)'
debug\moc_product.cpp:196: error: no match for call to '(QString) (QString&)'
debug\moc_product.cpp:197: error: no match for call to '(QString) (QString&)'
mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/minel/QMLUIProject_One-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug'
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [debug/moc_product.o] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe: *** [debug] Error 2
17:45:04: The process "C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building project QMLUIProject_One (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

Comment: The first thing to ask is: Have you included `<QString>`?

Comment: for those of you coming from MSVC, it is alot like the declspec __property  compiler feature -- except that it works on ALL c++ compilers instead

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me that you don't now how to use Q_PROPERTY.
This is example based on Your code on property _productid, I didn't include unnecessary stuff :

```
class Product: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString _productid READ _getProductid WRITE _setProductid)
public:

    QString _productid;
    QString _getProductid() const {return _productid;}
    void _setProductid(QString product){_productid = product;}
};
```

For READ You set name of function returning value of _productid.

For WRITE You set name of function setting value of _productid.

You on all this set the name of Your property, and Qt macro Q_PROPERTY set them as functions in moc_file. Compiler returns errors because he didn't find functions like QString Product::_productid() or void Product::_productid(QString).

Details of macro Q_PROPERTY and more examples: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/properties.html

Comment: if you put your properties' declarations inside another file and include them it will make moc choke on it, also, make sure you clean all/rebuild all, if you move the implementation of those functions from one module to another (one .cpp file to another would usually be the case) and avoid using .inc files in headers because the moc hates that :-)